# Laravel create user statement doesn't store specific columns

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel version 5.4 . I have a table called Users and each user has the below columns :

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $defaultValue = 0;

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('facebook_id')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->integer('newsletter')->default($defaultValue); // <-
            $table->bigInteger('category_1')->default($defaultValue); // <-
            $table->bigInteger('category_2')->default($defaultValue); // <-
            $table->bigInteger('category_3')->default($defaultValue); // <-
            $table->timestamp('unlocked_tip_of_category_1_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('unlocked_tip_of_category_2_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('unlocked_tip_of_category_3_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The problem is that when i use the function to create a user `category_1`, `category_2` and `category_3` don't take the new value which is 1.

After taking auth from facebook i use the below to store user's information :

```
 return User::create([
            'name' => $facebookUser->name,
            'email' => $facebookUser->email,
            'facebook_id' => $facebookUser->id,
            'avatar' => $facebookUser->avatar,
            'newsletter' => 0,
            'category_1' => 1,
            'category_2' => 1,
            'category_3' => 1,
        ]);
```

For example `name` changes to facebook user's name. Also i tried changing

`'name' => $facebookUser->name,`

to

`'name' => $facebookUser->name . " HEY",`

Which successfuly stored the name and + " HEY"  at the end. (Just to be sure that this runs).

Categories are `bigInteger` that means a `bigint(20)` type. I am thinking something happens with the default values which i've set it to `0`.

Any ideas? If you need any more information please let me know.

- From what i am trying to accomplish the best way to solve this is to change the `$defaultvalue` to `1`, but i don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Are the categories fillable? Where's your model?

Comment: Damn, i completely forgot it. Post it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the default laravel scaffolding then you need to ensure you're updating the default `App\User` model based on all columns you need to have as fillable:

```
  class User extends Model {

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','facebook_id','avatar','newsletter',
        'category_1', 'category_2', 'category_3'
  ];
   ...
  }
```

Same applies if you're creating your own model.